# Android preferences freeze when using ADT Plugin v9 with Eclipse on Mac?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, android-3.0-honeycomb

I just installed Eclipse 3.6.1 and added the ADT Plugin v9 on Mac OS X 10.6.6. When I go to preferences to add the path to the Android SDK, I get a popup with "Thanks for using the Android SDK!" with a checkbox for enabling usage stats. At this point, Eclipse freezes, and I can neither continue nor cancel.

I have to force quit Eclipse, and when relaunching, the same issue appears every time.

Any ideas how to avoid or bypass this? I suppose the popup will only be displayed until some config value has been set to first_launch = false or similar.

Comment: Having the same issue. Seems to be no way to agree or disagree with sending statistics. Very disappointing.

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but when I imported an existing Android project, I was able to get past the dialog, and it's now working as it should.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Ubuntu 11.04, so it doesn't appear to be Mac specific.

Answer (score 6):

Click on Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager
This will complain that android sdk location is not set in preferences and will popup the dialog saying "Thanks for using the Android SDK". You'll be able to click on proceed and dialog will disappear.

Now go to preferences and set your android sdk location.

Comment: Yeah, I can kind of understood that was how it was supposed to work. This screen is when it freezes, however, and none of the controls are clickable.

Answer (score 5):

This is sort of a bug. Ive reinstalled Eclipse and Android SDK yesterday and had the same problem.

The solution is, that er is another dialog opened in the background which catches the mouse focus. So Eclipse does not freeze but you cannot click anything because the Android Dialog has no focus.

Just open Expose (shop alle opened windows and dialogs), pick the other dialog which is opened in Eclipse and confirm it. After that you will be able to confirm the android dialog as well.

Comment: Thanks man.  This 'fixed' it for me.  For reference this was on Ubuntu and I used the Expose plugin to Compiz to achieve this, though now that I've done it I wonder if its possible via alt-tabbing to it.

Comment: In my case, the dialog that "conflicts" according to the explanation above, was the Preferences dialog.  I had to dismiss the Preferences dialog, then was able to click Proceed.

Answer (score 1):

It would help us if you could file a bug on this at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list so we can debug and hopefully fix it. We saw something similar to this on Windows a long time ago, but it's new on Mac as far as we know.

If you do file a bug, please include the Eclipse "edition"/package you downloaded (e.g. J2EE vs. J2SE, etc.), and what other plugins you've installed, if any.

In the meantime, you can get around the lockup by running a tool like ddms directly from Finder; that will cause the popup to appear outside of Eclipse, and you can dismiss it and move on. After that it should work from within Eclipse.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's still there as of today, when installing Eclipse 3.7 fresh.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new android app using wizard. It will pop the window too, but this window is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Hit ESC, click Proceed in the SDK Popup, reopen Preferences. This the easiest procedure.